# Shapefile for linked micromap is not working

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, error, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate the example provided in the micromap R package of a linked map with the poverty rate for the 50 US states. I am trying to achieve the same results with a Shapefile from Germany. Here is my code:

```
library(micromap)
library(ggplot2)

setwd ('C:/Users/Jesus/Dropbox/linked maps/Chapter4')
ger<-readShapePoly("germany3.shp")
edPov<-read.csv('gerpoverty.csv')

statePolys <- create_map_table(ger, 'VARNAME_1')
head(statePolys)
lmplot(stat.data=edPov, 
       map.data=statePolys, 
       panel.types=c('labels', 'dot','map'),
       panel.data=list('Id1','poverty',NA),
       ord.by='poverty',
       grouping=5, median.row=F,
       map.link=c('Id1','VARNAME_1'))
```

When I tried to parse it into a flat table for use with ggplot2 the procedure does not work (instead of having 16 observations it has 8000 plus observations). Also when I try to plot the linked map, the following error appears on screen:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, , ord.by) : undefined columns selected
```

Here is the link to the files in a zip file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c43k755aadvu2z6/germany.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your code were:

1. You did not have information on your .csv file about "poverty" like the `edPov` dataset from micromap package has.
2. The second value ("Varname_1") inside the argument `map.link` is not correct. You need to specify a column from the statePolys object, i.e., in that case it would be the "ID" column to match with the Id1 column in the edPov object.

So, to provide an example I added a column (column S) into the gerpoverty.csv file named "poverty".
I made up the poverty values (it was a range from #16 in the first row to #1 in the last row).

---

Here is the code I used:

```
library(micromap)
library(rgdal)

#read/import the germany3.shp shapefile in R. 
#the dsn argument is the directory and the layer argument is the shapefile name.
germany <- readOGR(dsn = "C:\\..", layer = "germany3")

#read gerpoverty.csv file from the directory it is stored.
edPov = read.csv("C:\\...\\gerpoverty.csv", sep=",")

statePolys <- create_map_table(germany, 'VARNAME_1')

lmplot(stat.data=edPov,         
       map.data=statePolys,
       panel.types=c('labels','dot','map'),
       panel.data=list('Id1','poverty', NA),
       ord.by='poverty',
       grouping=4, median.row=FALSE,
       map.link=c('Id1','ID'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, and yes there was something wrong with the csv file.